# How to connect to SQL Remote server in Laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, database, laravel, digital-ocean

I deploy my php laravel project (version 5.8) in digitalocean. I use remote SQL server for the database. I can connect to remote sql server by SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT, but when i use in laravel, i get this error

```
 "message": "SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (192.168.x.xxxx:1433) (severity 9) (SQL: select top 1 * from [users] where [email] = )",
```

here is my .env setting

```html
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=192.168.0.xxx
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=xxxx
DB_USERNAME=xxx
DB_PASSWORD=xxxx
```

```html
<?php

return [

   

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv'),

   

    'connections' => [


        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '192.168.x.xxx'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'xxx'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'xxx'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxx'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

    ],

    

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

   
    'redis' => [

        'client' => 'predis',

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

Comment: Can you try to connect with another programme ex? SQL server tool, Navicat or something like that.

Comment: yes, i try using Navicat and can connect to sql remote

Comment: can you check in php.ini extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7x_ts.dll
 extension=php_sqlsrv_7x_ts.dll

Comment: i use php 7.2 and i dont find extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7x_ts.dll in php.ini, can i add manually?

Comment: Yes, you can add .

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

> 'driver' => 'sqlsrv',

to

> 'driver' => 'mysql',